# VBA issues in Windows 11?

Tags: vba, windows, ms-access

I recently upgraded to Windows 11.  I'm fully updated and have the latest Office 365 updates as well.  Unfortunately, I'm finding that my "DoCmd.SetWarnings True" VBA actions no longer work in all my legacy Access apps. The action still works fine on my Windows 10 and Server 2019 devices.  Anyone else experiencing this (or other VBA issues?)

Thanks!

Comment: *no longer work* means what exactly?

Comment: Warning messages, e.g., "You are about to delete 10 row(s)", are no longer displayed.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that during the installation of Office 365 on my new Windows 11 laptop, the Action Queries check box in Options -> Client Settings is disabled by default.  This affected all databases on my laptop.  I enabled it and all works fine.